# Simple Logic Double Implication Question

Tags: logic

"True or false: if $p\land q$ is false, then $p↔q$ is also false."

I've said that this is true. For  $p\land q$ to be false, either $p$ must be false, or $q$ must be false, but not both, ie:

$p=1,q=0$  or  $p=0,q=1$

The double implication $p↔q$ will be false whenever $p$ and $q$ have opposing truth values, ie whenever:

$p=1,q=0$  or  $p=0,q=1$

Therefore, the initial statement should be true. Except that it's not; I've gotten the answer wrong and am not sure how.

Comment: If both $p$ and $q$ are false, then $p \wedge q$ is also false.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's been awhile and I'd forgotten that condition. Thank you!

Comment: The usual method of solution is to use a truth table where you list all cases ($n=2$ variables, hence $2^n=4$ cases). Then everything is clear and you will not miss anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not, in fact,  true.

Let's take a look at the truth-table for the connective "and": $\land$.

[image]

So in addition to the two cases you list in which $p\land q$ is false, we see that $p\land q$ is also false when both p is false, and q is false.

However, $p\leftrightarrow q$ is true whenever both $p$ and $q$ are true, and whenever both p and q are false:

[image]

Compare the bottom row of each truth-tables.

So, when $p$ is false, and $q$ is false, then $p\land q$ is false but   $(p\leftrightarrow q)$ is true (not false).

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: Suppose both $p$ and $q$ are false. Then $p\land q$ is false and $p\iff q$ is true.